# How to correctly index jsonb arrays and the fields in array elements in postgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, indexing, jsonb

a have a simple table of purchases consisting of id and jsonb column, like this:

```
CREATE TABLE purchase (id SERIAL, products JSONB)
```

Then and index:

```
CREATE INDEX idx_purchase_products ON purchase USING GIN (products);
```

The sample data are like this:

```
INSERT INTO purchase VALUES (
    1, jsonb('[
        {
            "country": 1,
            "type": 1,
            "size": 10,
            "color": 3
        }   
    ]')
),
(
    2, jsonb('[
        {
            "country": 1,
            "type": 1,
            "size": 10,
            "color": 3
        },
        {
            "country": 1,
            "type": 2,
            "size": 12,
            "color": 4
        },
        {
            "country": 2,
            "type": 1,
            "size": 12,
            "color": 3
        }
    ]')
),
(
    3, jsonb('[
        {
            "country": 1,
            "type": 1,
            "size": 10,
            "color": 3
        }   
    ]')
),
(
    4, jsonb('[
        {
            "country": 1,
            "type": 1,
            "size": 10,
            "color": 3
        },
        {
            "country": 1,
            "type": 2,
            "size": 12,
            "color": 4
        },
        {
            "country": 2,
            "type": 1,
            "size": 12,
            "color": 3
        }
    ]')
);
```

And some scenarios of searching:

```
SELECT * 
FROM purchase
WHERE products @> '[{"country": 1}]'

SELECT * 
FROM purchase
WHERE products @> '[{"country": 1, "type": 1}]'

SELECT * 
FROM purchase
WHERE products @> '[{"size": 12}]'

SELECT * 
FROM purchase
WHERE products @> '[{"size": 12, "color": 4}]'
```

It is expected, that the customer could search for combinations:

```
country,
country + type
country + type + size
country + type + size + color
country + size
size + color
type + color
etc.
```

And there is a big chance, the list of 4 field (country, type, size, color) will grow in future to 7-10.

And of course we want also search combinations like this:

```
.. WHERE products @> '[{"country": 1}]' OR products @> '[{"color": 4}]' OR products @> '[{"type": 1, "size": 10}]'
```

Estimated size of the table purchase is 9-12 millions rows (depending on season).

**Any idea how to implement the indexes to get the query result as fast as possible?**

Comment: This would be so much easier (and more efficient) with a properly normalized data model.

Comment: unfortunately there are several reasons the data must be stored in one table.

Comment: The GIN index type is, sadly, the only type able to work over Jsonb and Arrays (along with GIST). It's also a very heavy index, not as fast and reliable than other types. I know there are extensions to solve that kind of issue, if you have control over your engine.

Comment: I'd say that you already have the perfect index.

Comment: Side note: The schema of the JSON looks pretty static to me. You should consider not to abuse JSON but use relational means like (lookup and/or linking) tables and columns instead.

Comment: thanks for comments :)